# VS 2012 Trial Version and Code Coverage

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2012, code-coverage

Is it possible to obtain Code coverage numbers from VS 2012 Trial Version tool?

When I run my test cases (manually) after instrumentation, the `.coverage` file says my `.pdb's may not be present or may be incorrect.`

Is there something else i need to do?

For Instrumentation i do the Following:

- use vsinstr with coverage flag and instrument the .dll and .exe
- copy all .dll, .exe and .pdb file
- I execute the test cases.

I am using `Visual Studio ultimate 2012` Trial version downloaded from MSDN site

Comment: in the case of vs2010 i tried this :  tools ->options ->debugging->symbols->tick the check mark against microsoft symbol server and click ok     . please check

Comment: Yes, the same procedure works fine in 2008 and 2012

Comment: is this solved your problem?

Comment: a) are you using vsperfmon with the -coverage option b) are you using the right version of these tools ie 64-bit or 32bit

Comment: Yes, i am using the right version of tool (64 bit) and using vspermon with coverage option

Comment: @ArunC.B, as stated in the question, the issue i am seeing is for 2012

Comment: @NidaSahar You told                                                  >Yes, the same procedure works fine in 2008 and 2012

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`tools ->options ->debugging->symbols->tick the check mark against microsoft symbol server`

and click ok .